# Getting 'Unknown action in controller'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error :

"The action 'create' could not be found for ObjectController"

I know it should be obvious but I'm missing something, that's my controller :

```
class ObjectController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def create

  end
end
```

And that is my routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'object/index'
  get 'object/create'
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get
  resources :objets
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'object#index'
```

Comment: There are a few odd things going on here, but the most glaring is the spelling mistake here: `resources :objets` (should be `resources :objects`).  Also, by convention, you should always name your Controllers in the plural.  i.e. `ObjectsController` instead of `ObjectController`.  And then use errata's suggestion below.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found the problem, but I'll keep in mind your advices ;)

Comment: You need to point to `objects/index` (plural on objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that one was dumb, actually I had two directories and I wasn't modifying the right one, sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to scrap those routes and try something simpler like

```
resources :objects, only: [:get, :create, :show]
```

Then use

```
$ rake routes
```

To make sure your routes are as the should be. You will want a POST route to /objects to create a new object etc..

Comment: rake routes gives me the correct behavior but when I go to /objects/create I still have got that error

Answer (score 0):

Your routes could be greatly improved:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'objects#index'
  resources :objects
```

--

Next, the "standard" way to achieve what you're looking for is to use the `new` action; IE not the "create" action. If you wanted to use the `create` path name (instead of `new`), you'll be able to define it in the [`path_names` argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments):

```
#config/routes
resources :objects, path_names: { new: "create", create: "create" } #-> url.com/objects/create
```

To understand why you should be using `new` instead of `create`, you should look up [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), and how it pertains to [object orientated programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

---

Finally, your controller should be named in the plural:

```
#app/controllers/objects_controller.rb
class ObjectsController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Whilst you can call it whatever you like, Rails defaults to `plural` controller names, `singular` model names.